# How route two subnets when they are connect to a same router?

Tags: networking, router, routing, openwrt, subnet

I have a `Router` has 4 ethernet ports, `eth0` to `eth3`, with OpenWRT inside and such configurations:

- Interface `lan1` involves only `eth0`, IP address `10.10.0.1/16`
- Interface `lan2` involves only `eth1`, IP address `10.11.0.1/16`

The route table auto generated by OpenWRT is:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.0.0       *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
10.11.0.0       *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
```

So as you could see these two interfaces are different subnets.

When I ssh into the router I could ping both devices on 10.10.0.0/16 and 10.11.0.0/16. But when I was going to ping a device from 10.11.0.0/16 to 10.10.0.0/16 I only got `bytes from 10.11.0.1: Destination Port Unreachable`.

What I want to do is: be able to ping 10.10.0.0 from 10.11.0.0 and vice versa.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Does the router have an IP address set on eth0 and eth1? Also, make sure there isn't a firewall running on the device you are attempting to ping.

Comment: @Curtis The IP for `eth0` is `10.10.0.1` and for `eth1` is `10.11.0.1`. The iptables is running but I've changed all the rules to `ACCEPT`

Comment: Try disabling IP tables completely and see if that helps (as suggested here http://superuser.com/questions/587067/destination-port-unreachable-when-pinging-computer-in-another-subnet?rq=1 )

Comment: @Curtis Thanks for the post. I will check that.

Comment: @Curtis I just follow the hint from that post to add new zone forwarding rules and now these two subjects were able to ping each other.

Answer (score 0):

If the two devices on 10.10.0.0/16 and 10.11.0.0/16 are Windows devices, I don't believe they will accept inbound ICMP echo requests from a different subnet. You will likely have to create a custom rule through the Windows Firewall: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc972926(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But all my devices are running Linux

Comment: Ok, I guess check iptables on your two Linux devices and make sure they accept ICMP echo requests.

Comment: I found the reason is about openwrt zone forwarding rules. No need to make changes on devices.